# Databinding a Textblock in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, textblock

How does one simply "Databind a textblock to a codebehind C# variable"?

In my codebehind I have a public string variable and in my XAML I have 
    
but it does not work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am sorry, but this site is not meant for tutorials. These abound on the web by the way. But to help you get started: you must Always bind to *Properties* , not to public fields. Moreover,  have some reading about the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `BindingOperations` class. Something like this.

```
BindingOperations.SetBinding(myTextBlock, TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding("Whatever"))
```

Without knowing more about what you're trying to bind, this is the best answer you'll get.

And it's almost always better to use a real MVVM pattern rather than to do this sort of thing in codebehind.